# custom SimpleCursorAdapter to decode value

Tags: android, sqlite

i try to custom SimpleCursorAdapter to decode a value and set into textview but not working

my custom simplecursoradapter class:

```
public class simpledecode extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;
public simpledecode(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
        int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
}
@Override
public void setViewText(TextView v, String text) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.setViewText(v, text);
    v.setText(mDbHelper.base64toString(text));
}
```

my decode method:

```
public String base64toString(String text) 
{
    byte[] data1 = Base64.decode(text, Base64.DEFAULT);
    String text1 = null;
    try {
        return text1 = new String(data1, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.note.simpledecode.setViewText(simpledecode.java:24)
i think maybe textview or text is null

Comment: v.setText(mDbHelper.base64toString(text));

Comment: Tried this code see there is any exception thrown? v.setText(""+mDbHelper.base64toString(text));

Comment: Adding ""+ to v.setText on setViewText method

Comment: the same, null pointer
i dont know which is null :(

Comment: i put a log in settext, Log.d("debug","text " +text); and result text TVE9PQo=

Comment: my function decode is fail, i try to fix it

Comment: http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/how-to-base64-encode-decode-t11828.html Google just not support decode well :(

Answer (score 0):

This is because text is null in the line `byte[] data1 = Base64.decode(text, Base64.DEFAULT);`

You can add the null check at the beginning of the method

```
public String base64toString(String text) 
{
    if (text == null) return null;

    byte[] data1 = Base64.decode(text, Base64.DEFAULT);
    String text1 = null;
    try {
        return text1 = new String(data1, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: i try but it's not null.
i think if text null the decode of text is null too. so dont need 
    if (text == null) return null;

Comment: I tried passing the null value into `Base64.decode` and it throws an exception.